# Rust build.rs: Static linkage of library results in issues when trying to find the c++ std lib

Tags: rust, static-linking

I'm developing a `libfoo-sys` crate with low level bindings for an third-party C-library and a `libfoo`-crate on top of that. In the build-script of `libfoo-sys` I check out the original source from git.

I want to prevent that users have to globally install stuff into their system.

I build the library in the directory of the git submodule, and install the library locally into `./lib-out`. Inside `./lib-out` After building, I get the shared object file that has the following dependencies:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9eff6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f07870b0000)
        libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f078702b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0786e49000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0786c57000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f078734f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0786c3c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0786aeb000)
```

My build-script tells Rustc to use static linkage:
`println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=foo");`

However, as soon as I use static linkage, Rustc can't find C++ symbols. etc. I guess I have to also link all the dependencies manually. However, I don't know a generic way how `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=stdc++");` will work in the end. I can't find a `libstdc++.so` in my file system but only a `libstdc++.so.6` which is not compatible with `cargo:rustc-link-lib` (or at least I don't know how). Any advices?

PS: I'm aware of that you should refrain from linking glibc statically and I guess the same applies for the c++ std as well. However, primarily I'd like to figure out if it makes sense and brings a benefit to statically link the library and use the self compiled version instead of a globally installed version

Comment: It seems that Cargo doesn't respect the dynamic dependencies of the shared object when it links the library statically. Thus, you need to manually link the C++ lib like this: `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=stdc++");`